# Gulp Minify-CSS deletes CSS

Tags: html, css, gulp

Gulp minify-css is deleting css that I have recently added to my main css file. I have included the block of code that is being deleted by the gulp minify-css command. I have reorganized the css in my directory and also altered the order that cleanCSS is called.

**new-age.css:**

```
input[type=email]{
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 50px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

**gulpfile.js:**

```
// Minify compiled CSS
gulp.task('minify-css', ['less'], function() {
    return gulp.src('css/new-age.css')
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
});
```

Comment: Just Minify? Not compiling SASS or anything right?

Answer (score 0):

If your Just just looking to minify CSS try this below, Its old code but it should work still, let me know if it doesn't and i'll write you something up

```
var minfyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('minfy-css', function() {
    return gulp.src('css/new-age.css')
        .pipe(minfyCSS)
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```

Comment: Is minifyCSS not deprecated? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css

Comment: Try the updated code with the variable at the top of your file

Comment: an you please paste your gulp file in your post (The whole of it)

Comment: I figured out the issue. For whatever reason, it is creating a default css file named "new-age.css" in that directory. To fix it, I just created a separate css file.